# Spring REST and Future tasks

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, asynchronous

I have a REST service endpoint returning a `List<Offer>` as `json`. 
This service is calling different backend for each `Offer`. I'm aware it is possible to create an Async Rest service. However, I would like the client to use any `Offer` as soon as it's available and not once every `Offer` are ready.

I thought about two scenarios :

1. Using `Future` tasks would be the right answer if it wasn't a REST service. I didn't find a way to use it in a webservice context
2. Using two endpoints : 
   a) the first would return some unique "guid" for each `Offer`

   > public List`<String>` getOfferIds();

   b) the second would return an offer if it's ready

   > public Offer getOffer(String guid);

The second approach would remove the stateless context of my rest services.
Is this the best way or is there a better way to proceeed ?

Comment: This might help https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/03/deferredresult-asynchronous-processing-in-spring-mvc.html

Comment: This article looks very interesting, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the behaviour which you are referring to would get fulfilled if the application providing the OFFER would push the OFFER in a queue as and when available and then your application as a consumer can listen to that queue to proceed further.